# Regex negation - Apache

Tags: regex, apache, mod-proxy

I'd like to configure my Apache web server to serve everything that begins with "/static/" and anything else should be served by Tomcat.

For example:

- www.myDomain.com/static/anything
  should be served by Apache web server
- www.myDomain.com/notStatic/ should be server by Tomcat

Here is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName myDomain.com
ServerAlias www.myDomain.com

DocumentRoot /var/www

ProxyPassMatch (?!/static/.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1

</VirtualHost>
```

But this does not work. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

i did this by setting nginx for static to work on another ip and setting subdomain static.* to that ip

if you cant do that i would suggest setting up a proxy for both servers (for all traffic on 80 port)

and i dont recommend apache for static content. use nginx/lighttpd

also this should be asked on http://serverfault.com (IMHO)